# Why is noexcept not used in async libraries (like Asio and Beast)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio, boost-beast

Asynchronous functions often do not use exceptions.

Even on synchronous calls, Asio and Boost-Beast have overloads that take an output argument of type `system_error&` instead of throwing.

Asynchronous operations can't throw exceptions because the operation doesn't complete in the stack frame of the calling code¹.

*Is there a technical reason why these are not declared `noexcept`?*

Apart from possible performance advantages, I also think it would be useful as a hint for the user, because the user knows they don't need exception handling.

¹ technically, they might throw exceptions like on precondition checks or invalid arguments

Comment: i think they've been around longer than `noexcept` has been.

Comment: @DanielA.White Well, I'm pretty sure `throw()` which is older brother of `noexcept` was there before `std::thread`. My guess it is just an oversight in a library. As said in question - they are not throwing anything anyway.

Comment: @bartop `throw()` was fraught with problems and lack adoption to the extent that nobody used it, and guidelines actively warned not to use it.